# error in installing libpq-dev in ubuntu 14.04 after installing psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2, libpq, libpqxx

I am trying to install all requirements of a project so i run the command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

but it gives the error

```
Downloading/unpacking psycopg2==2.6 (from -r requirements.txt (line 58))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.6.tar.gz (367kB): 367kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/psycopg2/setup.py) egg_info for package psycopg2

    Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info

creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info

writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt

writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n'

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/psycopg2
Storing debug log for failure in /home/admin/.pip/pip.log
```

now i knew that i have to install postgresql-server so i used following command

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

all good till now and then i ran

```
sudo apt-get install python-psycopg2
```

and then i ran my command to install requirements again but got the same error and then i searched on google and tried

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

but i got following error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: krb5-multidev but it is not going to be installed
             Depends: comerr-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

now i am unable to detect and correct broken package...**please help me**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran the following commands to repair broken package and then i successfully installed Psycopg2 and Postgresql ...

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo apt-get install krb5-multidev
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0=1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 ibcomerr2=1.42.9-3ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0=1.0.1f-1ubuntu2
sudo apt-get install ibcomerr2=1.42.9-3ubuntu1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
apt-get install libssl-dev krb5-multidev comerr-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev krb5-multidev comerr-dev
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev krb5-multidev comerr-dev
sudo apt-get install libcomerr2
sudo apt-get install comerr-dev
sudo apt-get install libcomerr2
sudo apt-get install comerr-dev
sudo apt-get install comerr-dev
sudo apt-get install 1.42.9-3ubuntu1.3
sudo apt-get install ibcomerr2=1.42.9-3ubuntu1
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kos0/addRemoveDistribution.git
cd addRemoveDistribution
sudo ./enableDisableDistribution.pl enable security
sudo ./enableDisableDistribution.pl enable updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo apt-get update
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Just follow only  Steps

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/kos0/addRemoveDistribution.git
cd addRemoveDistribution
sudo ./enableDisableDistribution.pl enable security
sudo ./enableDisableDistribution.pl enable updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
sudo apt-get update
```

I Fixed issue by those above  steps